# Blackberry:lock application in portrait mode?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, screen-orientation, blackberry-storm

I want to start my application in portrait mode, always, on a BlackBerry Storm,
even then when device is in landscape mode.

How could I do that?

I know we can control the orientation after opening my app, by:

```
UiEngineInstance ui = Ui.getUiEngineInstance();
ui.setAcceptableDirections(Display.DIRECTION_NORTH);
```

but how to open the app in portrait mode?

Comment: Don't we all?  In the end, I just made the app handle both portrait and landscape.

Answer (score 5):

Use following just one line of code in constructor of each screen class.

Ui.getUiEngineInstance().setAcceptableDirections(Display.DIRECTION_PORTRAIT);

I also get the problem with this in OS 7 phone, So I have fixed by issue with using below code:

Ui.getUiEngineInstance().setAcceptableDirections(Display.DIRECTION_NORTH);

Comment: This is the correct way to do it (and only way that I'm aware of), but you should be aware that at least some users [have reported problems with it](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Issue-with-setAcceptableDirections-when-starting-in-a-different/td-p/196456) in some scenarios